# Throw exception or return null in retrieval method when user is not found in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a WPF - mvvm application. I have method in viewmodel that communicates with service layer and service layer communicates with database using entity framework. I am puzzled what to return if user is not found in database.

```
﻿using KnitterNotebook.Database;
using KnitterNotebook.Exceptions;
using KnitterNotebook.Models;
using KnitterNotebook.Models.Dtos;
using KnitterNotebook.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KnitterNotebook.Services
{
    public class UserService : CrudService<User>, IUserService
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _databaseContext;

        public UserService(DatabaseContext databaseContext) : base(databaseContext)
        {
            _databaseContext = databaseContext;
        }

       
        public async Task<string> GetNicknameAsync(int id)
            => (await _databaseContext.Users.FindAsync(id)
                ?? throw new EntityNotFoundException(ExceptionsMessages.UserWithIdNotFound(id)))
                .Nickname;

        public async Task<string?> GetNicknameAsync2(int id)
            => await _databaseContext.Users.FindAsync(id)?.Nickname;

    }
}
```

I want to return user's nickname, but what if somebody puts invalid id.
I think I can just throw an exception or return null nickname which is not expected as user always has a nickname. What approach could be better?

Comment: I would suggest that it depends on where the ID comes from. If the user is entering the value then the value being invalid is hardly exceptional, so throwing an exception would be inappropriate. If the ID is coming from the system though, the expectation would be that that ID would always exist, so it not existing would be exceptional.

Comment: Throwing an exception enforces to handle this exception everywhere. I dont see an advantage here.  Simply handle the case that the returned user is null. Why you provide a method to return just the nickname instead of returning a user-model? Then the caller can decide what he does with it. In case that the nickname can be null this would be an edge case you have to handle otherwise.

Comment: And just to add to the misery: This is a false dichotomy. There is not _only_ "null or Exception".

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8afwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what is the source of the request.
It's ID not username, so I suppose you obtained it in backend somehow, so then the user with that ID is supposed to be in the DB and if it's missing it's an error, so I would throw an exception.

But if it's something that went from frontend (like request for such user) than it's completely normal that there can be a request for user that is not present in the DB, so I would return null and then in controller just return 404.

Also remember that try catch blocks are slow, so do not use multiple try catch blocks. If you know something can not be present in the Db and it's not a problem (won't make any logic errors) than returning null is IMO good thing.